# Raspberry Pi 3 will not load SD Card

Tags: pi-3, boot, sd-card, act, activity-led

I have a very strange problem and have gone through 2 pi's atm. I have Raspberry Pi 3, I put an OMV imageon it [[1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmediavault/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20images/)]. The first time I boot up the Raspberry Pi it outputs and has a Kernal error:

I try rebooting it with different SD Cards and reformatted Cards, the Pi will not read the card anymore, the ACT light does not come one.

A friend lent me his Raspberry Pi 3 and an SD Card with a different image. I plug the Raspberry Pi into my setup, flash the SD Card with OMV, it works!

I find out my original Raspberry Pi's SD Reader is loose as when I use the second one it is a firm fit.

I set up OMV and then reboot it to test that I can shut this thing down. Now I have the same issue where the Pi will not read the SD Card or any others. NO ACT LIGHT!

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to troubleshoot further as I have reformatted multiple times on multiple different SD Cards.

**Update:**

I got it to work once, I picked up the case it was in and something clicked into place which made the SD readable?

I shutdown the raspberry Pi last night after setting everything up, hoping tomorrow it would work again. It will not read the SD Card, no ACT light, I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

For flashing the SD card I just flash it with Etcher and put the OMV[1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmediavault/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20images/) image on it, no other OS. I do not know what I am doing wrong but something weird is happening.

**Update 2:**

It Seems it is the case but I have not figured out what just yet, I unplugged everything and put it all back in. I then pressed on the case, no click, but it read the SD Card again. I am unsure what the case is doing that is preventing it from reading the SD Card in the first place.

I also got my first Raspberry Pi 3 to work with the image after taking it out of the case.

I will continue to fool around with it and post back here.

[[1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmediavault/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20images/)] https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmediavault/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20images/

Comment: Please describe the procedure you are using for creating the SD cards. And what OS version are you using?

Comment: Hey @MatsK, I provided more details, I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first like to thank the community I have figured out the issue and will leave the answer here in case someone else the a similar issue.

It was the [case](https://www.smraza.com/product/4-in-1-starter-kit-for-raspberry-pi-3-2-with-clear-casepower-supply2pcs-heatsinks-and-micro-usb-with-onoff-switch/) that was causing the issue of not reading my SD Card. I do not know why, however, my fix was to take everything out, put the Pi back in, screw in the screws until stop (do not force the screw to turn), plugin, boot up.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.